# Selecting a prize category based on two parameters

Tags: javascript, algorithm, ecmascript-6

I get an object with categories, first category has 2 types. Both types are in the first and second position but sorting is not constant.

I have to return category 1 with `playLevel === 2` when `bonusPlus` is true and category 1 with `playLevel === 1` otherwise.

Here is the code:

```
const getFirstCategory = (bonusPlus, prizeCategories) => {
  if (bonusPlus) {
    if (prizeCategories[0].playLevel === 2) {
      return [prizeCategories[0]];
    }
    return [prizeCategories[1]];
  }
  if (prizeCategories[0].playLevel === 1) {
    return [prizeCategories[0]];
  }
  return [prizeCategories[1]];
};
```

How can I reduce / beautify this code?

Comment: As per the [ask] guidelines, please explain what "this code" does, and what the parameters represent.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want the price category where `playLevel === (bonusPlus ? 2 :1)`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To make @kfx's answer more readable:

```
const getFirstCategory = (bonusPlus, prizeCategories) => {
  const bonusPlusLevel = bonusPlus ? 2 : 1;
  if (prizeCategories[0].playLevel === bonusPlusLevel) {
    return [prizeCategories[0]];
  }
  return [prizeCategories[1]];
};
```

Comment: just a little suggestion: `const bonusPlusLevel`

Comment: Yeah, I'm not a JS guy...

Answer (score 5):

Using the ternary operator and an extra variable would allow to reduce the size of the code:

```
const getFirstCategory = (bonusPlus, prizeCategories) => {
  var index = (prizeCategories[0].playLevel === (bonusPlus ? 2 : 1) ? 0 : 1);
  return [prizeCategories[index]];
};
```

Comment: The double ternary operator is a bit unreadable, isn't it?

Comment: I agree with @kyrill. You have reduced the code, but uglified it

Answer (score 3):

I would start by leaving the unnecessary condition brackets to make the program flow more obvious :

```
const getFirstCategory = (bonusPlus, prizeCategories) => {
  if (bonusPlus) {
    if (prizeCategories[0].playLevel === 2) {
      return [prizeCategories[0]];
    } else {
      return [prizeCategories[1]];
    }
  } else {
    if (prizeCategories[0].playLevel === 1) {
      return [prizeCategories[0]];
    } else {
      return [prizeCategories[1]];
    }
  }
};
```

Then use a variable for the result :

```
const getFirstCategory = (bonusPlus, prizeCategories) => {
  let firstCategory;
  if (bonusPlus) {
    if (prizeCategories[0].playLevel === 2) {
      firstCategory = [prizeCategories[0]];
    } else {
      firstCategory = [prizeCategories[1]];
    }
  } else {
    if (prizeCategories[0].playLevel === 1) {
      firstCategory = [prizeCategories[0]];
    } else {
      firstCategory = [prizeCategories[1]];
    }
  }
  return firstCategory;
};
```

Then mutualise the use of `[prizeCategories[i]]` :

```
const getFirstCategory = (bonusPlus, prizeCategories) => {
  let index;
  if (bonusPlus) {
    if (prizeCategories[0].playLevel === 2) {
      index = 0;
    } else {
      index = 1;
    }
  } else {
    if (prizeCategories[0].playLevel === 1) {
      index = 0;
    } else {
      index = 1;
    }
  }
  return [prizeCategories[index]];
};
```

Then mutualise the index double initialisation :

```
const getFirstCategory = (bonusPlus, prizeCategories) => {
  let lvlToCheck;
  if(bonusPlus) {
      lvlToCheck = 2;
  } else {
      lvlToCheck = 1;
  }
  let index;
  if (prizeCategories[0].playLevel === lvlToCheck) {
    index = 0;
  } else {
    index = 1;
  }
  return [prizeCategories[index]];
};
```

You can then make the code shorter (but not necessaraly more readable) with a ternary operator :

```
const getFirstCategory = (bonusPlus, prizeCategories) => {
  const lvlToCheck = bonusPlus ? 2 : 1;
  let index;
  if (prizeCategories[0].playLevel === lvlToCheck) {
    index = 0;
  } else {
    index = 1;
  }
  return [prizeCategories[index]];
};
```

Or even two :

```
const getFirstCategory = (bonusPlus, prizeCategories) => {
  const lvlToCheck = bonusPlus ? 2 : 1;
  let index = (prizeCategories[0].playLevel === lvlToCheck) ? 0 : 1;
  return [prizeCategories[index]];
};
```

You can shorter the code even more but I would stop there (if not before).

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of the fact that when adding a boolean to a number, the boolean will be coerced to 0 or 1.  That lets you simplify the function down to a single expression:

```
const getFirstCategory = (bonusPlus, prizeCategories) => [
    prizeCategories[(prizeCategories[0].playLevel === 1 + bonusPlus) ? 0 : 1]
];
```

You could golf the `condition ? 0 : 1`, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Why not? It's already on the way there. `(bonusPlus, prizeCategories) => [prizeCategories[1 - (prizeCategories[0].playLevel === bonusPlus+1)]`, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Although not strictly necessary, I would just use the Array's `find` function:

```
const getFirstCategory = (bonusPlus, prizeCategories) => {
  const bonusPlusLevel = bonusPlus ? 2 : 1;
  return prizeCategories.find( (cat) => {
    return cat.playLevel == bonusPlusLevel;
  });
};
```

(Borrowed partially from @kyrill)

Comment: This is not correct. You presume there is at least one element `cat` such that `cat.playLevel == bonusPlusLevel`, which might not be true. Moreover you presume that `find` searches the array from index 0 up, although this is a fairly valid assumption.

Comment: I think all the solutions make that assumption in one way or another, though the requirements aren't entirely clear. The spec for `find` is to return the first match. I would love it if JS did include a `bsearch` style find but it doesn't :(

Comment: None of the solutions makes either of the assumptions. BTW to do a binary search, the array would have to be sorted, which is kind of an overkill for array of two elements...

Comment: @kyrill I suspect the assumption actually is  true. "Both types are in the first and second position but sorting is not constant." would indicate you always have `playLevel` 1 and 2.

Comment: I may have misunderstood the description in OP's question. The way I understand it is: You have 2 types on the _first_ category. First category is `prizeCategories[0]` and its types are `playLevel == 1` and `playLevel == 2`. There is no mention of types of the second category -- no implication of the presence of `playLevel` in `prizeCategories[1]`. **However** that was not my point. What I said was "there might not be a `cat` such that **`cat.playLevel == bonusPlusLevel`**".

Comment: @kyrill That's exactly the point; if my interpretation is correct, you either have `prizeCategories[0].playLevel === 1 && prizeCategories[1].playLevel === 2` or `prizeCategories[0].playLevel === 2 && prizeCategories[1].playLevel === 1`

Comment: I see. That seems more sensible than my interpretation. In that case, using `find` is appropriate, especially if you plan on adding new categories.

Comment: @kyrill Yeah, that's what I was thinking. The op doesn't quite make it clear though.